# How is the opacity calculated by direct2d when a brush has both opacity and alpha channel less than 1

Tags: winapi, direct2d

In direct2d there is the base of all brushes `ID2D1Brush` which has an opacity set with `SetOpacity` and there is a solid color brush that uses floating point RGBA colors with alpha channel. There are other brushes but I didn't use them yet. If I set the opacity of the brush and used a color with alpha channel less than 1, how the resulting opacity will be determined? Will one of them override the other? Or the opacity will be the product of opacity value and alpha?

Comment: Since you're only ever asking about a single brush instance, I don't know what *"the other"* refers to. Regardless, [Using Color in Direct2D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/using-color-in-direct2d) explains how alpha blending works.

Comment: Oh, I see now, what you're asking. `SetOpacity` sets a constant, per-brush alpha value, but you can also set a per-pixel alpha value through `D2D1_COLOR_F`. Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1brush-setopacity) I would assume, that those alpha values get multiplied. For a solid color brush, where the per-pixel alpha value is constant across the brush, this offers two ways to accomplish the same outcome. But there are also other brushes (like a bitmap brush), where the per-pixel alpha value can vary across the brush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@IInspectable is correct (adding an answer to add photos).

From my complex brush editor:

Red picked with full opacity:

[image]

Red picked with 50% opacity (D2D1_COLOR_F 1,1,1,0.5f)

[image]

Opacity set per ID2D1Brush also set to 50%

[image]

So, they are multiplied. The idea is to have a global setting for brushes that contain many colors (linear, radial and bitmap). For a solid brush of course, there is not much meaning.